# "Use of undefined type" error even though I have forward declared the type

Tags: c++

I am making a chess game and I have some classes that roughly look like this.

```
struct MovementValidator;
struct Piece
{
    Piece(MovementValidator* movementValidator) :
        movementValidator{ movementValidator }
    {
    }

    virtual ~Piece() { delete movementValidator;  }

    enum class Type
    {
        PAWN
    };

    MovementValidator* movementValidator;
    virtual Type GetType() = 0;
};

struct PawnMovementValidator;
struct Pawn : public Piece
{
    Pawn() :
        Piece{ new PawnMovementValidator{} }
    {
    }

    Type GetType() override
    {
        return Type::PAWN;
    }
};

struct MovementValidator
{
    virtual void Validate(const Piece& piece) = 0;
};

struct PawnMovementValidator : public MovementValidator
{
    void Validate(const Piece& piece) override
    {

    }
};


int main()
{
    Piece* piece = new Pawn{};
}
```

I am getting an error on line `Piece{ new PawnMovementValidator{} }` in the Pawns constructor. The error is:

`Use of undefined type 'PawnMovementValidator'`

Why is this happening when `PawnMovementValidator` type is forward declared before being used?

Comment: The forward declaration is not a declaration. Move method definitions to .cpp or below MovementValidator declaration.

Comment: @S.M. I only have a .cpp file. Do i need to separate them out?

Comment: Define `PawnMovementValidator` before `Pawn`, or define the `Pawn` constructor after defining `PawnMovementValidator`. It can all be in one file.

Comment: A forward **declaration** is not a **definition**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct PawnMovementValidator;
```

is a *declaration*, not a *definition*. It tells the compiler that a struct exists with the name "PawnMovementValidator", but in the constructor of `Pawn` it needs to know the *size* of the struct in order to allocate memory for it. In other words, its definition needs to be known.

Solution: Not only declare the struct, but also *define* it before it is used.